# Пробел после каждой тысячи php

Tags: php

В переменной хранится некое значение количества аудитории. Отображается в формате: "Аудитория: 81345" (например). Как сделать так чтобы после тысяч был пробел, то бишь в формате "Аудитория: 451 834".

Сделал пробел после каждой третьей цифры, но способ не универсальный т.к есть цифры как 8612 где данный способ не сработает.

Способ:

```
$str = chunk_split($rows['value'], 4, ' ');
```

А вот сама переменная:

```
<strong>Аудитория: <?= $all_views ?></strong> <br>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Спасибо вам! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте функцию [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php).

```
number_format($rows['value'], 1, ',', ' ');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)